# How to allow user to use only some specific tags in laravel textarea

Tags: html, laravel, textarea

I am writing an article submission application in Laravel 5.7 and I want my users to be able to use some specific html tags only (Bullets and headings for example) in the text area. If any user enters any tags other than the specified then those tags should be stripped/removed from input on either server or client side. what is best approach for this and if you can share any code snippet that would be great. My application uses a simple form with a bootstrap 4 textarea and some other form elements which include text field, check boxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo strip_tags($request->nameoftextarea,<p><b><ul><li>);
```

You can use strip_tags function. Put the name of textarea request and you can put any html first tag after comma which you want to allow.

Comment: The second parameter of `strip_tags` must be enclosed between quotes. `echo strip_tags($request->nameoftextarea, "<p><b><ul><li>");`